# CSV file header changes in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file in which I want to change the headers names.

The current header is: `name,id` and I want to change it to `company,transit`

Following is what I wrote in script:

```
$a = import-csv .\finalexam\employees.csv -header name,id
foreach ($a in $as[1-$as.count-1]){  
    # I used 1 here because I want it to ignore the exiting headers.
    $_.name -eq company, $_.id -eq transit
}
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: You could just use `Get-Content` and write a manual header with commas

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking this... All you want to do is replace the header row, so set the new header as the first item of an array, read in the file skipping the first line and add it to the array, output the array.

```
"Company,Transit"|Set-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv
Get-Content C:\Path\To\Old.csv | Select -skip 1 | Add-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple like this:

```
$file = Get-Content C:\temp\data.csv
"new,column,name" | Set-Content C:\temp\data.csv
$file | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content C:\temp\data.csv
```

Collect the complete file contents and then write a new header. Then restore the rest of the file content while `-skip`ing the original header.